# How to migrate bean "with additional parameters" using @Assisted from Guice to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm working in a project that was implemented using Guice but we need to migrate it to Spring 3.x and we have this use-case below where beans need additional parameters for creation. How is this implemented in Spring? is it possible to implement using only annotations (and no xml)?

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.binder().install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().
                implement(Car.class, CarImpl.class).
                build(CarFactory.class));
    }
}

public interface Car {
    String getBrand();
    String getModel();
}

public class CarImpl implements Car {
    public CarImpl(@Assisted("brand") String brand, @Assisted("model") String model) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    String getBrand() { return brand; }

    @Override
    String getModel() { return model; }

    private final String brand;
    private final String model;
}

public interface CarFactory {
    Car create(@Assisted("brand") String brand, @Assisted("model") String model);
}

public class Client {
    @Inject CarFactory carFactory;
    final Car myCar;

    public Client() {
        myCar = carFactory.create("BMW", "530d xDrive");
    }

    void driveIt() { /* don't crash it */ }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client().driveIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need a factory bean that returns a CarImpl.

```
public interface CarFactory {
   Car create (String brand, String model);
}


@Bean
public CarFactory carFactory () {
   return CarImpl::new;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! does this work mixed with beans as well e.g. if create has a bean e.g. `create(String brand, String model, @Bean InsuranceContract insurance)`?

Comment: Modify the signature of the CarFactory create method and CarImpl constructor to accept the InsuranceContract.  I don't think you would want to create a CarFactory bean for every InsuranceContract Bean

Comment: Just made it up but we have that type of use case too.